# What do I do with this error I get when uninstalling Microsoft Office 2007?

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-office-2007

I am on a study to create an add-in in outlook using Visual Studio 2010. But as I had Microsoft Office 2007 it was showing an error while debugging. So, I thought of installing Microsoft Office 2010, after installation of Microsoft office 2010 only I noticed that I haven't uninstalled the Office 2007. While attempting to uninstall Microsoft Office 2007 it shows a dialog box saying,

> The Language of this installation package is not supported by your system.

What might be the problem and how could I uninstall Office 2007? Is there any possibility that I could go on continue my work without uninstalling Office 2007?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Fix it](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9669698) found in **Method 2** of [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218).

Comment: With my stupid thoughts I made it. I have just directly deleted the folders and files from my PC,but the problem was still remaining there that is, while trying to uninstall it from control panel it was showing the dialog box. So I tried installing office 2007 again and I find success in it and then tried uninstalling it from the control panel and the process went fine.Now i am installing MS office 2010 for my work. thanks to you @Louis

Comment: If you have found it helpful please check mark the solution so that future visitors know it is correct

Answer (score 1):

There are many reason of getting error during installation process of any application or software, one of the major error may be missing of your registry files which are being installed during your window installation, so you may have to re-install you window and then try again.

On the other hand there is possibility that the CD you have boughy from the market does not have all relevant files copied in that, so please always use authentic CD to install any software.